# I want to set minumum value in my seekbar android

Tags: android, seekbar

I want my seekbar having values from 33 to 80, I have read in Google, that we cannot set minimum in xml, so I add 33 to progress. But the thing is that my seekbar gets values from 33 to 113(max + 30). Any tips will be valuable for me, thank you.

```
TextView textView123;
SeekBar seekBar;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calc);
seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
     textView123 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progress);

      textView123.setText(seekBar.getProgress() + " ");
      seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
                new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
   int progress = 0;

        @Override
      public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, 
                                            int progresValue, boolean fromUser) {
       progress = progresValue + 33;
      }

      @Override
      public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // Do something here, 

      }

@Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         textView123.setText(progress + " ");
    }
      });
```

xml layout

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/backgroundpic" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@color/white" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:text="Quantity"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:max="80"
    android:progress="1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="91dp"
    android:text="33"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution:

Set max to the actual value you want *minus* the min value you programmatically add in `onProgressChanged`.

In your case, simply set max to 47 (80 - 33).